# bar graph not showing the first bar with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the following table in a .txt file

```
Group   Real        Imag        Cable       VSC P-mode  VSC Vdc-mode
A  -1.2739095e+02  -3.3612954e+02   4.9822998e-01   4.9309456e-01   8.6754595e-03
B  -3.6562225e+02  -1.5159071e-08   9.9466377e-01   5.3144496e-03   2.1780579e-05
C  -1.3022349e+02  -6.4822263e+01   0.0000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   5.0000000e-01
D  -2.9475053e+01  -3.6893573e+01   3.1371907e-03   4.9483474e-01   5.0202807e-01
E  -1.6348086e+01   2.1641636e-10   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00
F  -2.1006393e+02  -2.1418017e+02   1.6515906e-01   3.8119125e-02   7.9672181e-01
G  -9.9999998e+02   0.0000000e+00   2.7782889e-03   4.6066919e-01   5.3655252e-01
```

and I am trying to plot a bar graph with the following code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

% *** PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{standalone} % Pour les stand-alone
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 68 dvips colors à déclarer avant tikz
\usepackage{tikz} % Pour les figure Tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Pour tracer les courbes à partir de fichiers de données
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Pour pouvoir lire les tableaux des fichiers .txt
% *** PACKAGES END ***

\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % LATEX and plain TEX
\usepgfplotslibrary[units] % ConTEXt
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units} % LATEX and plain TEX
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.units] % ConTEXt
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} % pour définir la version de pgfplots


% LaTeX_Color_List={'BrickRed' 'Blue' 'ForestGreen' 'BurntOrange' 'DarkOrchid' 'Sepia' 'Aquamarine' 'RubineRed' 'Gray' 'Black'};

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=1\textwidth,
height=0.4\textwidth,
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=30pt,
enlarge y limits={upper, value=0},
    enlarge x limits = 0.1,
symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
%xtick={A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
    xlabel=Eigenvalues,
    ylabel=Participation Ratio,
    axis lines*=left,
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    cycle list={
{fill=Blue!85,draw=Blue!85},
{fill=Blue!50,draw=Blue!50},
{fill=Blue!20,draw=Blue!20}},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1}
    ]       

\addplot table[skip first n=1, x index=0, y index=3] {./DATA/VSC_EigenValues_Real_Imag_cable_Pf_Conv1Pf_Conv2Pf.txt};
    \addplot table[skip first n=1, x index=0, y index=4] {./DATA/VSC_EigenValues_Real_Imag_cable_Pf_Conv1Pf_Conv2Pf.txt};
    \addplot table[skip first n=1, x index=0, y index=5] {./DATA/VSC_EigenValues_Real_Imag_cable_Pf_Conv1Pf_Conv2Pf.txt};

\legend{DC Cable~~~~, P-mode VSC~~~~, Vdc-mode VSC}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and it almost works since I'm getting this:
[image]

However, as you can see, only the bar B C D E F G are plotted and not the bar A and I have no idea why. Can someone help me?

Even more strange is the fact that if I change "A" by "1" in the txt file and in the code, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `skip first n=1` from the `\addplot table` commands. If there is no `header=false` option for `table`, `\addplot table` uses the first row of your data file as column names.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{a.txt}
Group   Real        Imag        Cable       {VSC P-mode}  {VSC Vdc-mode}
A  -1.2739095e+02  -3.3612954e+02   4.9822998e-01   4.9309456e-01   8.6754595e-03
B  -3.6562225e+02  -1.5159071e-08   9.9466377e-01   5.3144496e-03   2.1780579e-05
C  -1.3022349e+02  -6.4822263e+01   0.0000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   5.0000000e-01
D  -2.9475053e+01  -3.6893573e+01   3.1371907e-03   4.9483474e-01   5.0202807e-01
E  -1.6348086e+01   2.1641636e-10   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00
F  -2.1006393e+02  -2.1418017e+02   1.6515906e-01   3.8119125e-02   7.9672181e-01
G  -9.9999998e+02   0.0000000e+00   2.7782889e-03   4.6066919e-01   5.3655252e-01
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

% *** PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{standalone} % Pour les stand-alone
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 68 dvips colors à déclarer avant tikz
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Pour tracer les courbes à partir de fichiers de données
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % Pour pouvoir lire les tableaux des fichiers .txt
% *** PACKAGES END ***

\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % LATEX and plain TEX
\usepgfplotslibrary[units] % ConTEXt
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.units} % LATEX and plain TEX
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.units] % ConTEXt
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} % pour définir la version de pgfplots


% LaTeX_Color_List={'BrickRed' 'Blue' 'ForestGreen' 'BurntOrange' 'DarkOrchid' 'Sepia' 'Aquamarine' 'RubineRed' 'Gray' 'Black'};

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=1\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=30pt,
    enlarge y limits={upper, value=0},
    enlarge x limits = 0.1,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G},
    xlabel=Eigenvalues,
    ylabel=Participation Ratio,
    axis lines*=left,
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    cycle list={
      {fill=Blue!85,draw=Blue!85},
      {fill=Blue!50,draw=Blue!50},
      {fill=Blue!20,draw=Blue!20}},
          legend style={at={(0.5,-0.4)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1}
    ]       

\addplot table[ x index=0, y index=3] {a.txt};
\addplot table[ x index=0, y index=4] {a.txt};
\addplot table[ x index=0, y index=5] {a.txt};

\legend{DC Cable~~~~, P-mode VSC~~~~, Vdc-mode VSC}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow I didn't know that. Thanks!